# AJAX login screen with web method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

I'm kind of new at this and am having a hard time wrapping my brain around what exactly is supposed to be returned via an AJAX call to a web method and how I'm supposed to handle it.  I'm attempting to create a simple login screen.

Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" />
            <button id="loginbutton" onclick="UserLogin()" type="submit">login</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function UserLogin() {

        var postData = JSON.stringify({
            "username": $("#username").val(),
            "password": $("#password").val()
        });
        alert(postData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.aspx/AuthenticateUser",
            data: postData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: callbackfunction,
            error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
        });


    }

    function callbackfunction(result) {
        alert('callback');
        if (result.d) {
            alert('success');
        }
    }
```

Web Method:

```
     <WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function AuthenticateUser(sID As String, sPassword As String) As Boolean


    Dim db As New ProjectDatabase
    Dim ed As New EncryptDecrypt

    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT [USER_ID] FROM [USERS] WHERE [USER_ID] = '" & sID & "' AND [PASSWORD] = '" & ed.Encrypt(sPassword) & "'"

    'will return the result of the query, either a user id or nothing
    Dim sRtn As String = db.GetSQLData(sSQL, db._cnnSQL)

    If sRtn = "" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

So If I understand it right, I should be able to return either a true or false from the web method, but for some reason I'm not getting in there (not hitting on breakpoints) and both ends of the AJAX should throw up a message box.  However that doesn't happen either.

I know this question has been asked and I've read multiple articles but can't seem to still get it right.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: In regards to a login endpoint, I would suggest that the response content is not the biggest concern.  The response code is.  By simply returning 200 (OK) or 401 (Unauthorized), your client knows exactly whither or not the user was able to login.

Comment: instead of returning false, `Throw New WebFaultException(Of ErrMessage)(str, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)` That should make it go into the error part of your ajax when there is an error.

Comment: Use same variable names in `AJAX` and `WebMethod`. That is either `username` or `sID`.

Comment: What if the user types this into the textbox? '; DROP TABLE [USERS]

Comment: if you're not hitting the server breakpoints then check in your browser's tools to see what response you're getting to your request (assuming it's being made and you don't have other client-side errors). Also, your login button has type="submit" which will make it post back, so possibly the ajax never happens due to this behaviour. Change it to type="button".

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem.  Changing to "button" did it.

Answer (score 0):

Your login button has `type="submit"` which will make it initiate a full postback, so almost certainly the ajax request never happens due to this behaviour.

Change it to `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

HTML -

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" />
        <button id="loginbutton" onclick="UserLogin()" type="submit">login</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT -

```
function UserLogin() {

    var postData = JSON.stringify({
        "username": $("#username").val(),
        "password": $("#password").val()
    });
    alert(postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.aspx/AuthenticateUser",
        data: "{'data': '" + postData+ "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: callbackfunction(result),
        error: function (msg) { debugger;alert(msg); }
    });


}

function callbackfunction(result) {
    debugger;
    alert('callback');
    if (result.d) {
        alert('success');
    }
}
```

Web Method -

```
using NewtonSoft.Json;

<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function AuthenticateUser(data As String) As Boolean


Dim db As New ProjectDatabase
Dim ed As New EncryptDecrypt
Dim dt As New Datatable =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(data);

Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT [USER_ID] FROM [USERS] WHERE [USER_ID] = '" & dt.Rows(0).Item("username") & "' AND [PASSWORD] = '" & ed.Encrypt(dt.Rows(0).Item("password")) & "'"

'will return the result of the query, either a user id or nothing
Dim sRtn As String = db.GetSQLData(sSQL, db._cnnSQL)

If sRtn = "" Then
    Return False
Else
    Return True
End If

End Function
```

this will get the data and let you debug on your browser